# Create reusable camera and gallery

Tags: java, android

I want to create a class to handle camera and gallery that I can use on different fragments.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GalleryAndCamera {
    private Activity activity;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> takePictureLauncher;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pickImageLauncher;
    private ImageCaptureListener imageCaptureListener;

    public GalleryAndCamera(AppCompatActivity  activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        takePictureLauncher = activity.registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        if (data != null) {
                           
                            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                            saveImageToGallery(photo, activity.getApplicationContext());
                            imageCaptureListener.onImageCaptured(photo);
                        }
                    } else if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                       
                    }
                }
        );

        
        pickImageLauncher = activity.registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        if (data != null) {
                            
                        }
                    } else if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void takePicture() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureLauncher.launch(cameraIntent);
    }

    public void pickImage() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickImageLauncher.launch(galleryIntent);
    }
    public void setImageCaptureListener(ImageCaptureListener listener) {
        this.imageCaptureListener = listener;
    }
}
```

```
public class Myfragment extends Fragment implements ImageCaptureListener{


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMyfragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        GalleryAndCamera galleryAndCamera = new GalleryAndCamera((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity());
        
        binding.idBtnWDCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              
                Helper.clickSound(getContext());
                imageHandler();

               
            }
        });
}
```

problem:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hepszolg.birdcontrol, PID: 11293
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.myproject.MainActivity@288c540 is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The illegal state exception is happening because you are trying to register the activity result launchers from an activity context. Instead do it from the fragment. Fragments also have a registerForActivityResult() member function.

> GalleryAndCamera galleryAndCamera = new GalleryAndCamera((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity());

Change to:

```
GalleryAndCamera galleryAndCamera = new GalleryAndCamera(this);
```

> public GalleryAndCamera(AppCompatActivity  activity)

Change to:

```
public GalleryAndCamera(Fragment fragment)
```

Comment: This may work, but the camera does not pop up the permission request window.
Error:Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera }

Comment: Camera apps do not pop up permission request windows. Unclear what you mean.

Comment: Should you ask if:
Do you allow the app to take pictures and videos?
-While using the application
-Just now
-Block

Comment: Still unclear what you wanna say. But more important: Is the `attempting to register while current state is RESUMED` problem gone now? You might confirm that instead of a `This may work`.

Comment: Yes, the gallery part works.

Comment: You are expected to say that switching from activity context to fragment was the solution of your problem. Sigh..

Comment: If the gallery part does not work now then it has never worked, Pretty different probem. Try to understand what this error means as it is pretty simple.